# How to set 2 different time display in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 textbox in vb.net form.
In one textbox it displays system time.
In second textbox i want to display time that is 2 hrs later than system time.
How can i do that with timespan.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a timespan? You can do it with a `Date` variable.

```
Dim dt As Date = Date.Now
textbox1.Text = dt.ToString()
textbox2.Text = AddTimeZoneDiff(2, dt)

Private Function AddTimeZoneDiff(offset As Double, dt As Date) As String
 Return dt.AddHours(offset).ToShortTimeString()
End Function
```

Comment: +1. IMHO, not worth its own function. Also, be consistent with `ToString`s, i.e. if it's `ToString()` for `TextBox1.Text`, should be `ToString()` in `TextBox2.Text`. Otherwise make both `ToShortTimeString()`

Comment: @Neolisk, I was making the best attempt at the output that I could make out from the question given. Thanks though...